# Filter awk system output with awk?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, nested, system

I need to use awk to see what users are logged in the computer, create a file with their names and inside that file print the pid of the process they're running. I've used this, but it does not work:

```
who | awk '{for(i = 0; i < NR; i++)
    system("ps -u " $1 "| tail +2 | awk '{print $1}' >" $1".log")
}'
```

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to SO, thank you for posting your efforts in your question. Could you please post sample of your expected  output and sample of your input(may be output of `ps` command?) with few more details like are you passing any arguments to your script? Kindly do add these details in your question and let us know then, cheers.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Thanks for your welcome! Yes, imagine there are 2 users in the system, the exit of who will be:
user1
user2
Two iterations of the loop, for each user, i need to call ps -u and save the pids of the process they are running (the first column) in a file with their names, i dont know if you understand what i want to do.
Thanks!

Comment: Could you please try following `ps -u | awk '{print $1,$2}' > out_file` and lemme know if this is what you need? If you are Happy with it, I will make this as an answer then, cheers.

Comment: IMHO, I believe `ps -u` is also giving same output which you need user name and its pid. Then may be we need not to use `who` here?

Comment: I need to use both, is an exercise and this is a requirement, save the pid of the users logged in the system

Comment: Could you please try following, `cat details.ksh
who_ami_i=$(who | cut -d' '  -f1)
ps -u $who_ami_i | awk -v who="$who_ami_i" 'FNR==1{print "PID user";next}{print $1,who}'` once and lemme know? I created a script named `details.ksh` and ran it, worked for me, since only 1 user logged in in my system it looks good in output vice, kindly do check once.

Comment: Please show input (result of `who`) and corresponding requested output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve your goal of using `awk` to create those files, I would start with `ps` rather than with  `who`. That way, `ps` does more of the work so that `awk` can do less. Here is an example that might work for you. (No guarantees, obviously!)

```
ps aux | awk 'NR>1 {system("echo " $2 " >> " $1 ".txt")}'
```

**Discussion:**

- The command `ps aux` prints a table describing each active process, one line at a time.  The first column of each line contains the name of the process's user, the second column its PID.  The line also contains lots of other information, which you can play with as you improve your script. That's what you pipe into `awk`. (All this is true for Linux and the BSDs. In Cygwin, the format is different.)
- Inside `awk`, the pattern `NR>1` gets rid of the first line of the output, which contains the table headers. This line is useless for the files you want `awk` to generate.
- For all other lines in the output of `ps aux`, `awk` adds the PID of the current process (ie, `$2`) to the file `username.txt`, using `$1` for `username`. Because we append with `>>` rather than overwriting with `>`, all PIDs run by the user `username` end up being listed, one line at a time, in the file `username.txt`.

**UPDATE (Alternative for when `who` is mandatory)**

If using `who` is  mandatory, as noted in a comment to the original post, I would use `awk` to strip needless lines and columns from the output of `who` and `ps`.

```
 for user in $(who | awk 'NR>1 {print $1}')
 do
     ps -u "$user" | awk 'NR>1' > "$user".txt
done
```

For readers who wonder what the double-quotes around `$user` are about : Those serve to guard against globbing (if `$user` contains asterisks (`*`)) and word splitting (if `$user` contains whitespace).

I will leave my original answer stand for the benefit of any readers with more freedom to choose the tools for their job.

Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: I don't usually read comments to other people's posts, so thank you for that information, Ravinder.